# Воспроизведение нескольких звуков одновременно

Tags: python, аудио

У меня есть программа, воспроизводящая соответствующий по номеру звук при нажатии на клавишу:

```
import pygame
import keyboard as kb


pygame.init()

btns = list('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm')

while True:
    for i in range(26):
        if kb.is_pressed(btns[i]):
            pygame.mixer.music.load(f'{i}.mp3')
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Но если нажать другую кнопку, пока воспроизводится звук первой, то первый звук прекратится, а второй начнётся. Мне нужно, чтобы звуки накладывались друг на друга и никакой не прекращался, пока не проиграется до конца. Как это можно сделать и какие ещё есть способы воспроизведения звуки на python?

Comment: Вначяле программы: `pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(26)` в цикле :`pygame.mixer.Channel(i).play(pygame.mixer.Sound(f'{i}.mp3'))`

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.